# Can I add insulation over the original layer in my new home's basement?

Tags: insulation, basement

I am looking to finish the basement in my new house that has insulation wrap installed in the basement.  The insulation wrap is an R12.

After studding the basement can I add additional installation to increase the R factor in front of the existing wrap?

Is there anything I should do or consider doing to the existing installation?

I understand I should not add a 2nd vapor barrier, is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. What is "insulation wrap"? A photo would be great.

Comment: Also, why are you interested in adding more? Basements aren't a major source of heat loss. R12 is reasonable for all but the most severe climates.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on your location. Aside from removing the wrap insulation and doing a spray foam insulation (which is flammable), the best job includes tar paper on the concrete(so any moisture coming through the wall doesn't wet the insulation) then the insulation in the walls with the bottom 6 inches left out and a 6 mm vapour barrier stopping short of the floor. The reason why the gap is so air can get into the wall and the moisture can get out. 
Also be sure to put in adequate vents (including cold air returns) to ensure good air flow.